# Handling post notifications that may take more than 20 seconds

Tags: opayo

We are integrating with SagePay using the server integration method.

The notification POST from SagePay calls back to a PHP script our side.

Our PHP callback itself has to call several methods on an external webservice.

Sometimes, due to network latency, our callback script takes over 20 seconds to run. SagePay doesn't like this and reissues a new notification POST. This results in our callback ultimately running twice, or more, which is less than ideal (sends out multiple payment complete emails etc). Basically SagePay keeps issuing notifications until it gets a response in less than 20 seconds.

We can't just ignore the latest POST request from SagePay as they 'forget' about any previous notifications and look to receive a response from the most recent one. We can't do anything about network latency either.

Does anyone have any advice on what to do in such a situation?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing your Notification callback could do is to check the transaction table and if not already updated then update the transaction table with the message and continue with your business processing, or else discard the repeated call. I wasn't aware that Sagepay only accepted a response from the most recently issued Notification callback, and this isn't mentioned in the integration guide.

You should still aim to speed it up, however. Have a think about how you might send your emails in a cron/scheduled job every minute, so that your customers are not held-up waiting for your third parties to respond. Rather than sending emails in your Notification callback you can simply add rows to an email_queue table, to be processed later by the cron job.

Comment: Thanks Ian, storing the message and then continuing with the processing would not work. SagePay website states: 'If your server does not respond to the notification post we will send another attempt.  Your server must respond to latest notification post that is sent by Sage Pay. Any responses to older to notification posts Sage Pay will ignore it.'

In the end we've managed to speed up the calls somewhat which has helped. We have to wait for the web service calls to run to know whether to return 'ok' to SagePay or not.